# Create a Cordova UWP Plugin with a UIElement

Tags: windows, cordova, xaml, uwp, cordova-plugins

Currently, we have a Cordova plugin and a UWP Class library. The library is using native UIElements for different UI workflows. Is there a way to display those UIElements? I read, that XAML views can't be displayed. Is there a workaround somehow?

Comment: You use a webview to display the html page? and you want to display a XAML view on the top of the webview?

Comment: Cordova is using the WebViews. So, we just have the WebView environment. But yes, somehow use the XAML view, or communicating with it.

Comment: You can implement a custom plugin to decide when to display the XAML view and hide the web view in the meantime.

Comment: Perfect! This might actually work. Do you know how? We can't find anything on the web.

Comment: It's a little complex to describe clearly, I don't have a demo for you sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cordova is using the WebViews. So, we just have the WebView environment. But yes, somehow use the XAML view, or communicating with it.

Yes. Cordova is using the WebViews in Android and IOS, but not in Cordova UWP. The low level of Cordova UWP actually is using javascript. The XAML view also is not available.
So, your requirement is impossible.